# Pandas equiv of "Select x from y groupby x"?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this code

```
dfUsers = df.groupby('UserID').count()
```

which gives me back a list of user IDs plus counts. It works for what I need it for but was wondering if there was better code out there for getting back just the unique list of userIDs, and not the count, from a dataframe that has users appearing more than once?

The SQL equivalent would be: Select userID from dataframe groupBy userID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
dfUsers = df['UserID'].unique()
```

Alternatively, you can use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) which returns a `DataFrame`:

```
dfUsers = df['UserID'].drop_duplicates()
```